# Loop Year and Months

Tags: php

How can I loop the year and months with some given dates?
Below is my current code and I can't get it running

```
$Startdate = '2017-01';
$Enddate = '2018-06';

 for($selectedDate = date("Y-m",$begin); $selectedDate <= date("Y-m",$end); $selectedDate++){
    $resultY = date("Y",strtotime($selectedDate));
    $resultM = date("m",strtotime($selectedDate));

    echo $resultY;
    $echo resulthM;
}
```

The output should be:

```
2017    1
2017    2
2017    3
2017    4
2017    5
2017    6
2017    7
2017    8
2017    9
2017    10
2017    11
2017    12
2018    1
2018    2
2018    3
2018    4
2018    5
2018    6
```

Comment: if  `$selectedDate` is `2017-1` then what you expected from `$selectedDate++` ?

Comment: `$echo resulthM;`  typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If I were you** :) I will try with `DateTime` class to generate months between your `$Startdate` and `$Enddate`. See [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
 $start    = new DateTime('2017-01');
 $end      = new DateTime('2018-06');
 $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
 $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
 foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("Y-m") . PHP_EOL;
 }
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/FvmS4

Comment: Thanks this looks good however this only give me 2017-01 to 2018-05

Comment: thanks with this i just added `$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end->modify('+1 month'));` and it works :)

Comment: Glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$startDate = new \DateTime('2017-01-01'); 
$endDate = new \DateTime('2018-06-01');

for($selectedDate = $startDate; $selectedDate <= $endDate; $selectedDate->modify('+1 month')) {
    // format $selectedDate;
    $resultY = $selectedDate->format('Y');
    $resultM = $selectedDate->format('m');

    // print content
    echo $resultY;
    echo "\t";  // print tab
    echo $resultM;
    echo "\n";  // print new line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you were familiar with strtotime, you can amend your code to the following to execute the desired results.

```
$begin = date("Y-m", strtotime("2017-01")); // Replace this with date to begin.
$end = date("Y-m"); // Replace this with date to end.

for($selectedDate = date("Y-m", strtotime($begin)); $selectedDate <= date("Y-m", strtotime($end)); $selectedDate = date("Y-m", strtotime($selectedDate . "+1 Month"))){
    $resultY = date("Y", strtotime($selectedDate));
    $resultM = date("m", strtotime($selectedDate));

    echo $resultY;
    echo $resultM;
}
```

However, equally, user don't angry me, has an answer that will allow you to use the DateTime objects and manipulate them instead, so if you'd rather switch over your code to something potentially more reliable, you could do that also.

Comment: oh yes there it is. i will try this one also. so i think $selectedDate++ didnt work when you work with dates in loop

Comment: @JydonMah Actually I believe it's the fact your even incrementing $selectedDate. $selectedDate++ means add one to $selectedDate... But add one what? I believe that's where the issue lay. In mathematics terms, you had the digit, but not the unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime::modify` and walk the months forward

```
$Startdate = '2017-01';
$Enddate = '2018-06';

$DateTime = new DateTime($Startdate.'-01');

echo $DateTime->format('Y')."\t".$DateTime->format('n')."\n";

do{
   $DateTime->modify('+1 months');

   echo $DateTime->format('Y')."\t".$DateTime->format('n')."\n";

   if($DateTime->format('Y-m') == $Enddate) break;

}while(true);
```

Just make sure the `Enddate` is a valid Year/Month and happens after `Startdate` or in this example you'll loop forever.

There are probably other ways to do the loop that avoids that.

But I didn't see `DateTime::modify` used in an answer so I thought I would throw one together.

Output:

```
2017    1
2017    2
2017    3
2017    4
2017    5
2017    6
2017    7
2017    8
2017    9
2017    10
2017    11
2017    12
2018    1
2018    2
2018    3
2018    4
2018    5
2018    6
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36a0a9ca9fcff1b76c6a6a2cb976c9076caad5cf)

I usually use this method when I want to make a select/option for stuff like months.  But I use this format `str_pad($DateTime->format('n'),2,' ',STR_PAD_LEFT).' - '.$DateTime->format('F')`  OR `' 2 - February'`, notice the space on the left ... :) ... that way they all line up nice and neat like.

Anyway, cheers!